# How come a site is indexed but not indexed?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, search-engine-indexing, google-index

An example URL: islamqa.info/ar
The site is indexed in Google Webmaster Tools as per this image
[image]

But When I use google site: operator, I get

Your search - site:islamqa.info/ar - did not match any documents.

Hence, the site is indexed but not indexed!

Note1: All other languages, e.g. islamqa.info/en, everything is OK! Just the Arabic language has this problem.

Note2: Other search engines like Bing and DuckDuckGo shows correct results!

Comment: Can you work with John to see if this question can be edited to be on-topic? It is an interesting question. Thanks!

Comment: @Jonh-conde Since this is my first post, I may be missing the obvious but I don't see why you considered it off-topic. The question is generic and my site is just an example to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Maybe Google expects your browser language to be Arabic?!

Comment: @JohnConde Can you help to give guidelines on how to make this question more acceptable? It seems interesting enough to give interesting answers.

Comment: @closetnoc It is too site specific. Basically this question is like a website review where the answers will not be useful to future visitors.  I don't see a way to make this question on-topic here other than to ask it in chat.

Comment: @w3d The problem has nothing to do with browser language or country. You can confirm this yourself

Comment: @JohnConde Please, try to look for the question from another angle. Having a site that GWT claims to have thousands of pages indexed but the site: operator claims otherwise, is a very generic issue that many can encounter. I am not asking for any review of my site and I am not even interested in someone pointing me to what I could do better because I already know many things that I can improve and few problems that I need to fix.

Comment: I respect what John is saying. He is right. Can you try and reword the question in a fashion that is less site specific and a question that may pertain to another site? I am not sure how that would look besides the obvious removal of the site name. It may require a bit of thought besides the obvious.

Comment: Part of the problem is once you remove the site specific information the question becomes impossible to answer as you need to visit the site to review it for a possible problem. See the dilemma?